# autocorrelation of the input in tensorflow/keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, batch-processing, convolution

I have a 1D input signal. I want to compute autocorrelation as the part of the neural net for further use inside the network.
I need to perform convolution of input with input itself.
To perform convolution in keras custom layer/ tensorflow. We need the following parameters
`data shape is "[batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]",
filter shape is "[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`

There is no batch present in filter shape, which needs to be input in my case

Comment: How many in_channels do you have?

Comment: 2 inchannels are there.

Comment: And these channels should not be mixed in the convolution, right?

Comment: Yes, Each channel needs to be independent. I can also modify my code to make the number of channels 1. That can be done easily

Comment: I'm trying to think of a solution, but this is not trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow now has an `auto_correlation` function.  It should be in release `1.6`.  If you build from source you can use it right now (see e.g. [the github code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/python/ops/sample_stats.py)).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution.

By self convolution, I understood a regular convolution where the filter is exactly the same as the input (if it's not that, sorry for my misunderstanding).

We need a custom function for that, and a `Lambda` layer.

At first I used `padding = 'same'` which brings outputs with the same length as the inputs. I'm not sure about what output length you want exactly, but if you want more, you should add padding yourself before doing the convolution. (In the example with length 7, for a complete convolution from one end to another, this manual padding would include 6 zeros before and 6 zeros after the input length, and use `padding = 'valid'`. Find the [backend functions here](https://keras.io/backend/))

**Working example - Input (5,7,2)**

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import *
import keras.backend as K

batch_size = 5
length = 7
channels = 2
channels_batch = batch_size*channels

def selfConv1D(x):
    #this function unfortunately needs to know previously the shapes
    #mainly because of the for loop, for other lines, there are workarounds
    #but these workarounds are not necessary since we'll have this limitation anyway

    #original x: (batch_size, length, channels)

    #bring channels to the batch position:
    x = K.permute_dimensions(x,[2,0,1]) #(channels, batch_size, length)

    #suppose channels are just individual samples (since we don't mix channels)
    x = K.reshape(x,(channels_batch,length,1))

    #here, we get a copy of x reshaped to match filter shapes:
    filters = K.permute_dimensions(x,[1,2,0])  #(length, 1, channels_batch)

    #now, in the lack of a suitable available conv function, we make a loop
    allChannels = []
    for i in range (channels_batch):

        f = filters[:,:,i:i+1]
        allChannels.append(
            K.conv1d(
                x[i:i+1], 
                f, 
                padding='same', 
                data_format='channels_last'))
                    #although channels_last is my default config, I found this bug: 
                    #https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/8183

        #convolution output: (1, length, 1)

    #concatenate all results as samples
    x = K.concatenate(allChannels, axis=0) #(channels_batch,length,1)

    #restore the original form (passing channels to the end)
    x = K.reshape(x,(channels,batch_size,length))
    return K.permute_dimensions(x,[1,2,0]) #(batch_size, length, channels)


#input data for the test:
x = np.array(range(70)).reshape((5,7,2))

#little model that just performs the convolution
inp= Input((7,2))
out = Lambda(selfConv1D)(inp)

model = Model(inp,out)

#checking results
p = model.predict(x)
for i in range(5):
    print("x",x[i])
    print("p",p[i])
```

Comment: Done something similar to your implementation but using keras custom layer. So there is now way right now to escape the batch size pre-initialization?

Comment: I don't know a way to avoid it. But this is only because of the "for" loop. We can't iterate tensors. But maybe we can take `K.eval(K.shape(x))[0]` in the loop. In this case we can apply some workarouds in the other lines that use batch sizes....

Answer (score 0):

You can just use tf.nn.conv3d by treating the "batch size" as "depth":

```
# treat the batch size as depth.
data = tf.reshape(input_data, [1, batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels])
kernel = [filter_depth, filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]
out = tf.nn.conv3d(data, kernel, [1,1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
```

Comment: I think using this will make the values along depth axis mixed right?

Comment: Right. Isn't that what you want? Could you given some examples to illustrate what you need?

Comment: Let's take a batch of 16 bivariate time series, each of 100 time steps. I need autocorrelation of each of the variable.
(16,100,2) will the input size. I need to convolve just the time series with itself along axis=1, i.e 100 in the above example. the output be something like (16,?,2)