# Convolve 2 tensors within a model - Keras

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I need to convolve 2 tensors and then apply convolutions to the output.
I am using a lambda layer for this but I am not able to make this work.

```
def corr(input):
a = input[0]
b = input[1]
x = tf.nn.convolution(a, b, padding='SAME')
return x

# Apply on im1
filtered_im1 = conv1(i1)
filtered_im1 = conv2(filtered_im1)
filtered_im1 = pool(filtered_im1)
drop_filtered_im1 = drop(filtered_im1)
filtered_im1 = conv3(drop_filtered_im1)
filtered_im1 = conv4(filtered_im1)
filtered_im1 = pool2(filtered_im1)
im = drop2(filtered_im1)

# Concatenate Im with flow
imflow  = Lambda(corr)([im, conv_f2]
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46803541/autocorrelation-of-the-input-in-tensorflow-keras/46822170#46822170

Comment: However, I have variable batch sizes each time? How to tackle that ?